# JSF 2.0: Has the presence of JSR-303 bean validation an impact on custom JSF-Validators?

Tags: jsf-2, bean-validation, myfaces, hibernate-validator

I'm now in charge for a JSF 2.0 application, where everything is validated through custom validators which totally blows up the *.xhtml files. I tried to migrate the validation to JSR-303 bean validation, which works fine.

Since JSR-303 doesn't validate class level constraints, I wan't to keep one custom validator, which validates, that a request form, has at least on field filled.

The validator is registered to every field and gets a string array with the name of the other fields, which it has to check for input. The problem is, when JSR-303 ist present on the classpath, the properties for the custom validator aren't set and then it is not aware of the names of the other fields. The validator is still triggered but ends up with a message, that no input has been given.

I've already take a look on the log file output, but the only difference is

```
11:22:50,403 INFO  [Version] Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
11:22:50,450 INFO  [ExternalSpecifications] MyFaces Bean Validation support enabled
```

instead of

```
11:02:10,472 INFO  [ExternalSpecifications] MyFaces Bean Validation support disabled
```

Another difference is the following output, which appears, when the validation is triggered for the first time, when JSR-303 is present:

```
11:23:09,906 INFO  [_ExternalSpecifications] MyFaces Unified EL support disabled
11:23:09,906 INFO  [_ExternalSpecifications] MyFaces Bean Validation support enabled
```

I'm using MyFaces 2.0, Hibernate Validator 4.2 on a JBoss 5.1 jdk6

**Update**:

```
<cc:formular bean="#{bankenBean}">
        <h:outputLabel for="bankleitzahl">
            <span class="kurztaste">B</span>ankleitzahl:</h:outputLabel>
        <h:inputText id="bankleitzahl" accesskey="b" size="10" maxlength="8"
            value="#{bankenBean.bankleitzahl}">
            <audi:notEmptyValidator dependsOn="bic name ort"
                detail="Eines dieser Felder muss gefüllt sein." />
        </h:inputText>
        <h:message for="bankleitzahl" errorClass="fehlertext" />
        <h:outputLabel for="bic">B<span class="kurztaste">I</span>C:</h:outputLabel>
        <h:inputText id="bic" accesskey="i" size="12" maxlength="11"
            value="#{bankenBean.bic}">
            <audi:notEmptyValidator dependsOn="bankleitzahl name ort"
                detail="Eines dieser Felder muss gefüllt sein." />
        </h:inputText>
        <h:message for="bic" errorClass="fehlertext" />
        <h:outputLabel for="name">
            <span class="kurztaste">N</span>ame der Bank:</h:outputLabel>
        <h:inputText id="name" accesskey="n" size="35" maxlength="58"
            value="#{bankenBean.name}">
            <audi:notEmptyValidator dependsOn="bankleitzahl bic ort"
                detail="Eines dieser Felder muss gefüllt sein." />
        </h:inputText>
        <h:message for="name" errorClass="fehlertext" />
        <h:outputLabel for="ort">
            <span class="kurztaste">O</span>rt der Bank:</h:outputLabel>
        <h:inputText id="ort" accesskey="o" size="35" maxlength="35"
            value="#{bankenBean.ort}">
            <audi:notEmptyValidator dependsOn="bankleitzahl bic name"
                detail="Eines dieser Felder muss gefüllt sein." />
        </h:inputText>
        <h:message for="ort" errorClass="fehlertext" />
    </cc:formular>
```

This is the point, where the notEmptyValidator is used. It's defined in a facelets.taglib.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd">

<namespace>http://rzf.finnrw.de/audi</namespace>
<tag>
    <tag-name>notEmptyValidator</tag-name>
    <validator>
        <validator-id>de.finnrw.rzf.audi.NotEmptyValidator</validator-id>
    </validator>
    <attribute>
        <name>dependsOn</name>
        <type>java.lang.String</type>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>detail</name>
        <type>java.lang.String</type>
    </attribute>
</tag>
```

When JSR-303 is present on the classpath, this custom validator is still registered an triggered. But it hasn't got it's properties set and is therefore not aware of the fields which it has to check.

Comment: _Converter_s and _Validator_s are two different things really. Can you clarify by adding some code, eg the converter code as well as the jsp code.

Comment: Argh ... stupid fingers. I wrote custom converter but I meant custom validators. I'll update my post and provide code.